# How to match arabic words with reg exp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this: "سلام علیکم" which is a two word arabic phrase. I want to match first word with regular expression. If it was english I would test `/^[a-zA-Z]*/`. how can I do it with arabic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a character class which will match arabic language only:

```
/^[\p{Arabic}]*/
```

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) is the full reference

Answer (score 4):

Arabic characters are :

```
'\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC'
```