# how to check if string contains arabic character

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, arabic

I want to check whether string contain arabic text or not.

I  tried [this](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW556KW556&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex+for+arabic+characters+ios) all answers but nothing is working.

Can some one let me know what regular expression should I use?

---

```
nickNameTF.text = @"eweسبيب";
NSLog(@"nickNameTF.textnickNameTF.text===%@", nickNameTF.text);
NSString *emailRegex = @"\p{Arabic}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];


if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:nickNameTF.text]) {
    DTAlertView *myAl = [DTAlertView alertViewWithTitle:localize(@"myErr") message:localize(@"srNicc") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:localize(@"dismiss") positiveButtonTitle:nil];
    [myAl setDismissAnimationWhenButtonClicked:DTAlertViewAnimationSlideTop];
    [myAl showWithAnimation:DTAlertViewAnimationSlideBottom];

    nickNameTF.enabled = YES;
    nickNameTF.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
```

---

```
nickNameTF.text = @"يسيس";
// nickNameTF.text = @"adsيسيس";
// nickNameTF.text = @"ads";
NSLog(@"nickNameTF.textnickNameTF.text===%@", nickNameTF.text);
NSString *emailRegex = @"\\p{Arabic}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

if (![emailTest evaluateWithObject:nickNameTF.text]) {
    NSLog(@"not trueeeee");
}

if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:nickNameTF.text]) {
    NSLog(@"trueeeee");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the code here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355526/ios-regular-expression-arabic

Comment: @stribizhev : I use `\\p{Arabic}` now but still no alertview..

Comment: @nhahtdh : still not working

Comment: @stribizhev : Yes, I am using contains..

Comment: @stribizhev : can u check my if condition? is it right? can u post full code that works with you?

Comment: This works for me: `NSString * emailRegex = @"(?s).*\\p{Arabic}.*";
   NSPredicate * emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];`, see nhahtdh's answer.

Comment: @stribizhev : for me its not working... any gues? can u post full code? I want to check whether string contains any arabic character...

Comment: @stribizhev : check my updated question... i check with all three option.. it gives me not trueee for all...

Comment: Here is my [sample code that is working for me](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUGdIenE2amg0YlU).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### NSPredicate

Following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9), the code should be written as:

```
NSPredicate *emailTest =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES %@", @"'\\\\p{Arabic}'"];
```

Your current code is missing the single quotes around the regular expression. You also need to double escape `\`, since there are 2 layers of escape: one is string literal syntax of Objective-C, and the other is string literal syntax of NSPredicate.

Since you want to check whether the string contains an Arabic character, the regex should be

```
(?s).*\p{Arabic}.*
```

`(?s)` is an inline flag which makes `.` matches any code point without exception.

Plugging it in the code above:

```
NSPredicate *emailTest =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES %@", @"'(?s).*\\\\p{Arabic}.*'"];
```

In [predicate format string syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868), only `MATCHES` works with regex, and it asserts that the whole string matches the regex, so the regex needs to be written to match the whole string.

### NSRegularExpression

Alternatively, you can use [`firstMatchInString:options:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/firstMatchInString:options:range:) in NSRegularExpression.

In this method, you only need to escape once in Objective-C string literal. Since the method will search for a matching substring, your regex doesn't have to be written to match the whole string.

Modifying from the example code in the documentation:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\p{Arabic}"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:nickNameTF.text
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [nickNameTF.text length])];
if (match) {
    // If there is an Arabic character
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I wrote the @nhahtdh answer in swift :)

```
var str = "منص••"
var str2 = "منص"
var str3 = "Hello منص••"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?s).*\\p{Arabic}.*")

if predicate.evaluateWithObject(str3) {
    print("arabic")
}

// if you need to Left to right flow
let addLTR = "\u{200E}\(str3)"
```

Answer (score 4):

Convenient way using extension

```
extension String {
    var isArabic: Bool {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?s).*\\p{Arabic}.*")
        return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

And you can just use something like following:

```
var str = "منص••"
if str.isArabic {
    print("Arabic")
}
```