# Password validation with regex Arabic and English characters in swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I want to validate the password to include at least 1 Arabic or English letter and at least 1 Arabic or English number and at leats 8 length password, my old code that was made for English only was like :

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$"
if (!NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@",passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)){
    return false
}
```

and then i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423510/3086197) for Arabic characters and digits, then i tried to merge both like this :

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[A-Za-zء-ي])(?=.*٠-٩\\d)[A-Za-zء-ي٠-٩\\d]{8,}$"
if (!NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@",passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)){
    return false
}
```

please advise what's wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Try `"^(?=.*[a-zA-Za-z\\u0621-\\u064A])(?=.*[0-9\\u0660-\\u0669])[a-zA-Za-z\\u0621-\\u064A0-9\\u0660-\\u0669]{8,}$"`

Comment: Note you may just match any letter (not just English and Arabic) with `\p{L}`. Also, try `"^(?=.*\\p{L})(?=.*\\d)[\\p{L}\\d]{8,}$"` although it will also match `Владимир19812`

Comment: See my answer with various options. It is working and tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am reading it now

Comment: [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033) may really benefit you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an English or Arabic letter regex (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423510/3086197) you linked to, also, see [this answer, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only)) is `[a-zA-Za-z\u0621-\u064A]` and an English or Arabic digit regex is `[0-9\u0660-\u0669]` you may use

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\\u0621-\\u064A])(?=.*[0-9\\u0660-\\u0669])[a-zA-Za-z\\u0621-\\u064A0-9\\u0660-\\u0669]{8,}$"
```

NOTE: you do not need the outer `^` and `$` anchors because `MATCHES` requires the pattern to match the whole string input.

Another way to match an Arabic letter with ICU regex used in Swift is to use `[\p{L}&&[\p{script=Arabic}]]` (it is an intersection inside a character class, it matches any letter but from the Arabic character set). Same with a digit: `[\p{N}&&[\p{script=Arabic}]]`. Then, the regex will look like

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}A-Za-z]])(?=.*[\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}0-9]])[\\p{L}\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]{8,}$"
```

So, here

- `[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}A-Za-z]]` - any letter but it should belong to either ASCII letters or Arabic script
- `[\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}0-9]]` - any digit but either from `0-9` range or Arabic script
- `[\\p{L}\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]` - any letter or digit but only from the ASCII `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z` and Arabic script.

Note also, that in order to match any letters, you may use`\p{L}` and to match any digits you may use `\d` (they are Unicode aware in ICU library). So, *in case t does not matter if the letters or digits are Arabic, English, Greek or whatever, you may use

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*\\p{L})(?=.*\\d)[\\p{L}\\d]{8,}$"
```

Comment: Dear Stribizew, can you give me a hint how to just add one more detail, i want that validation to accept also 0 or more special characters, i found an example but it force at least one special character, but i want to just make it available for the user to user, so i made the code like this but it didn't work : 
 
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}A-Za-z]])(?=.*[\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}0-9]])[\\p{L}\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]{8,}$"

Comment: @Alshcompiler If you just want to let users enter any chars, replace `[\\p{L}\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]{8,}` with `.{8,}`.

Comment: but user will have to enter at least 1 Arabic/English letter and number right ?

Comment: but why when i add the special characters to that validator like this it doesn't recognize those special characters like this : 

`[\\p{L}\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}|?>.<,:;~`’]]{8,} `

Comment: in case i don't want some other characters :"D

Comment: @Alshcompiler It does not work because you placed them into the intersected class,but the other class does not match punctuation. You may use it like `(?:[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}]]|[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()\\-_=+{}|?>.<,:;~’]){8,}` - make sure you escape the `-` or put it at the end of the character class.

Comment: Thanks again for your continuous support :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i want to add special characters in this let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}A-Za-z]])(?=.*[\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}0-9]])[\\p{L}\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]{8,}$" . How to add ?

Comment: i try (?:[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}]]|[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()\\-_=+{}|?>.<,:;~’]){8,} but its not working for me.

Comment: @ChandanJee ``"^(?=.*[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}A-Za-z]])(?=.*[\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}0-9]])[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{S}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]{8,}$"``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is not Working for me. 
 func isArabicCheckTextSufficientComplexityUpperCaseNumber() -> Bool{        let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[\\p{L}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}A-Za-z]])(?=.*[\\p{N}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}0-9]])[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{S}&&[\\p{script=Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]]{8,}$"
            let texttest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex)
            let result = texttest.evaluate(with: self)
            print("\(result)")
            
            return result
        }

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please help me?